# HTML & JS: how to open website with viewport on mobile devices (iOS) with small viewport by default?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

By default in my app I have two resolutions (width):

`1024px+` & `520px`

and I have such viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=520, initial-scale=0.5" id="vwPrt">
<script>
  window.onload = function () {
    if(screen.width > 521) {
        var vpEl = document.getElementById('vwPrt');
        vpEl.setAttribute('content','width=520, initial-scale=1');
    }
    if(screen.width > 970) {
        var vpEl = document.getElementById('vwPrt');
        vpEl.setAttribute('content','width=1024, initial-scale=1');
    }
  }
</script>
```

and css:

```
...

@media all and (min-width:0px) and (max-width:520px){...}
...
```

and sometimes on iOS devices, I first see css styles for a big resolution (1024px+), and only after scaling, or reloading page, do I get 520px for iPad and iPhone (in portrait mode).

What am I doing wrong?

How can I detect width on the fly and apply it directly without the blinking screen when in desktop mode?

Comment: Is there a good reason for specifying the width and not using `width=device-width` so that the device can adapt the layout viewport?

Comment: @denmch
i have min width 640px - and if device width is 540px - it will scroll - it's a bad idea

Comment: @brabertaser1992 why don't you just redirect the page after you get the screen size?

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend a much easier way. It is possible to link towards a separate CSS file depending on the media query.

What you have to do is the following:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' media='all and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 520px)' href='css/small_devices.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='all and (min-width: 520px) and (max-width: 970px)' href='css/medium_devices.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='all and (min-width: 970px)' href='css/large_devices.css' />
```

In that case you can also split the content very easily and everything becomes better readable due to the fact that you keep the media queries separated.

You have to put these link inside the `<head>` of your document. Doing this will also ensure that this loaded before the content is showed.

Comment: I'm not downvoting, but this doesn't solve the problem. 1st, unless you have a mega site with hundreds of thousands of lines of CSS, it's always better to ship all your CSS together in a single file. eg. 26,000+ lines of CSS runs about 350Kb - but only 45Kb gzipped - which is less expensive than 3x 15Kb requests. 2nd, no matter what styles you load, the viewport meta tag controls the size at which the browser will render your page - which is what the OP is needing help with. There is no css-only solution for this question.

Answer (score 3):

Use [bootstrap](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/download/) with mobile first solutions.
No need to track resolutions per JavaScript or write a whole bunch of mediaqueries.

Answer (score 0):

From MDN:

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At
>   this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all
>   the images, scripts, links and sub-frames have finished loading.

To make your script fire before everything has loaded, you should be able to do this, without `window.onload()`:

```
if (screen.width > 521) {
   document.getElementById("viewport").setAttribute("content", "width=520; initial-scale=0.5");  
}
if (screen.width > 970) {
   document.getElementById("viewport").setAttribute("content", "width=1024; initial-scale=0.5");  
}
```

Comment: will it work everytime? i mean will it find viewport node before load?

Answer (score 0):

Mayby you can test with the "orientation" in your CSS

```
@media all and (orientation:portrait) and (min-width:0px) and (max-width:520px){...}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't see any reason to wait for `window.onload` as that would very likely cause a flash of unwanted content. Your code will also set the value twice for screens larger than 970px - which is just unnecessary. You can just write the meta tag like this for the most performant and immediate results. I would put this as high up in your HEAD as possible, ideally before any styles or other scripts:

```
<script>
    var width = 'device-width';
    if(screen.width > 521) {
        width = '520';
    }
    if(screen.width > 970) {
        width = '1024';
    }
    document.write('<meta name="viewport" content="width=' + width + ', initial-scale=0.5" id="vwPrt">');
</script>
```